# API working in Sandbox but not reporting to site when live

Tags: php, api, paypal

Hi we have a site built in php and made an paypal app and are using the REST API. The flow should be user makes deposit > payment is authorized > user is redirected to user account on site and sees the deposit > deposit and transaction id show in site admin.

This works perfectly in sandbox but when we set it to live (and changed the credentials in the site code) and made some small transactions to test it, the live paypal acct is getting the deposits but its not showing in the user account or in the sites admin panel.

Not sure where we went wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the app you created is not getting the completed payment information from PayPal.

One way you can get the information your application needs is using webhooks.

From the PayPal Developer Site:

> Webhooks are user-defined HTTP callbacks that receive events for the subscribed event types. Webhooks are asynchronous, the order is not guaranteed, and idempotency may lead to the same event being sent more than once. The webhooks configurations include: create, list, update, and delete.

Below are three links to the overview of using Webhooks, sample code and the Webhooks Simulator.

[Webhooks Overview from PayPal Developer Site](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/)

[Sample Code from PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-information)

[Webhooks Simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#webhooks-simulator)